# A variable value is not being reflected in all places in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am loading a saved variable from localStorage to Angular scope.
I have HTML:

```
 <p>{{passcodeEnabled}}</p>
 <p ng-show="passcodeEnabled==true">Hello there!</p>
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="passcodeEnabled">
```

For example, I set it to `true`.
The issue is it is shown as true in first paragraph, but goes as undefined/false in second paragraph and checkbox.

Why do these differ and how to make this binding work properly?

Comment: Are you sure passcodeEnabled isn't stored as a `"true"` string instead of a `true` boolean? In that case, I don't think your bindings will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, Yann, yes, I have already checked it and it was the case. So I am casting strings to booleans now and it works fine!